# pyserial Serial.read() returns b''

Tags: python, stm32, pyserial, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm try to reproduce the result of benchmarking at [here](https://github.com/mupq/polymul-z2mx-m4)

I use STM32F429 Nucleo-144 board and Ubuntu 20.04 with VMWare on Windows10.

When I run `benchmarks.py` in terminal, `Serial.read()` returns empty bytes, b''.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
import serial

dev = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 115200,timeout=10)

def benchmarkBinary(binary):
    print("Flashing {}..".format(binary))
    subprocess.run(["st-flash", "write", binary, "0x8000000"],
               stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    print("Flashed, now running benchmarks..".format(binary))
    state = 'waiting'
    marker = b''
    # This parses test vector output starting with a number of leading '=',
    #  and expects a hashtag '#' after the test vector output.
    while True:
        x = dev.read()
        if x == b'' and state == 'waiting':
            print('x =', x)
            print('state =', state)
            print("timed out while waiting for the markers")
            return benchmarkBinary(binary)
```

And the printed result is as following:

```
Flashing benchmark-kindi256342.bin..
Flashed, now running benchmarks..
x = b''
state = waiting
timed out while waiting for the markers
Flashing benchmark-kindi256342.bin..
```

What should I do? Is there any way to run the binaries?

```
x = b''
state = waiting
```

is added by me and it is not in the original code.
And the message above is printed repeatedly since `x` and `state` values are fixed.

I checked the initial baud rate of STM32F429 Nucleo-144 is 115200, which is written in the original code.
And I changed `/dev/ttyUSB0` to `/dev/ttyACM0` since there is no `/dev/ttyUSB0` in the board.

I checked there is no problem with `ST-link` and `gcc-arm-none-eabi`.
Also I checked the board is connected correctly.

I assume that there may be some problems with virtual environments, but I can't sure.

I also tried to run other binary code, but there is no messages even codes are flashed well, and pressed RESET button.

Comment: First off, don't use a recursive call to repeat the function; just use another loop if it's needed, but I don't see why the existing `while True:` loop isn't sufficient. Second, *what part of the code is supposed to cause `state` to change?* Third, *why should `dev.read()` read anything*? Why do you expect that there is any data to read from the device, and what should it look like?

Comment: "I changed /dev/ttyUSB0 to /dev/ttyACM0 since there is no /dev/ttyUSB0 in the board." What happens if you try reading from `/dev/ttyACM0` at the command line (like with `dd`)?

Comment: This code is not mine, so I don't know why the while loop is used. However, I assume that the loop is needed when there is no data from `.read()` or `state` is 'waiting'. To help your understand, please see the `benchmarks.py` code in the repository. The code has too many characters so I can't copy and paste here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel And there is no data has been read by read(). Only b'' returned after reading.

Comment: Right; so what I am thinking is, perhaps there is a problem outside of the code  that prevents the device from offering any data to read.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Can you explain it in detail? I assume the 'prevention' is from OS(e.g. kernel), or the virtual machine, but not sure.

Comment: It could be any number of things, I think. I don't have this hardware, so I wouldn't be able to test it.